# JQuery - sequential HTML traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a simple JQ task to complete and I can't find an answer. I have some generated HTML :-

```
<p align= center >
<table cellspacing=0 border=1>
<caption align=bottom class=captiondataframe></caption>
<tr><td>
<table border=0 class=tablecorporate>
<tbody> 
<tr class= firstline > 
    <th>&nbsp;  </th>
    <th>WEEK  </th>
    <th>PERIOD  </th>
    <th>ILPROD  </th>
    <th>CNME  </th>
    <th>QTY  </th>
    <th>SP  </th>
    <th>REV  </th>
    <th>COST  </th>
    <th>VA  </th>
    <th>VAP</th> 
</tr>
```

I need to remove the `<tr><td>` elements on line 4 using JQuery. I had thought about using $(tr:first).remove() but I suspect this will remove the wrong elements on subsequent page loads.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you remove the <tr><td> using jQuery then your HTML will be rendered invalid as <table> will be within <table> - given that the HTML is generated, why not fix the thing that generates the HTML? Seems an odd thing to want to do, after the HTML has been created.

Comment: you can use jQuery `$(tr:eq(3)).remove()` function in eq u can pass the index of row. remember it starts with zero(0). per your question in understand that you want to remove the additional `<tr><td>` which is appearing in your question. this is the wrong rendering of your `HTML` u need to see how is this `HTML` rendered. if it dynamic you need check your code to close `<tr><td>` on proper location.

Comment: Is it possible to change the way the HTML is generated? In any case, what is the desired result? Do you want the second table to be one the elements of the first table or what?

Comment: jQuery operates on the DOM that your browser extracts from the HTML. You cannot use it to fix broken HTML, only to change the DOM. [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) might be the better choice.

Comment: Agreed fixing HTML is best solution, but not possible. Code is output from Statistical Analysis System and is part of much bigger analysis. I think the only way to achieve this is with a standalone JS or VB script. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: As mentioned above, it would invalidate. Perhaps you could remove one of the table-elements as well? Are there corresponding closing tags for the <tr>- and <td>-elements further down?

Comment: Extremely hackish, but `var el = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]; el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/<tr><td>/, "");` I believe to be the answer to the literal question you asked. I must echo the previous commenters, though, that is probably not quite the result you're really looking for. Is there more context you could give like a larger sample of html or possibly describe why you believe removing those two elements but not their closing tags is the solution?